# Format date time using jq

Tags: bash, date, sh, jq, iso8601

I have a bash (sh) script that makes several API calls and returns string values.
One of them is a 'created_at' attribute of the JSON object returned.

`released_at=$(echo -E "${json_response}" | jq -r '.[0].released_at'")`

Value returned in ISO 8601 format: `"released_at": "2023-09-27T17:36:07.182Z"`

I would like it to be displayed as `Wednesday, September 27, 2023`

What would be the shortest way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: If you need `sh` compatibility, you shouldn't use `echo -E` at all. See the [POSIX spec for echo](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- the only thing `echo -E` is allowed to do in a compliant implementation is write the string `-E` on output. [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) on [unix.se] goes into (much!) more detail.

Comment: As for your question -- look at `strptime` and `strftime` -- one will parse out your current string, the other will form the result into a different format of your choosing.

Comment: (that said, the standardized/portable `strftime` and `strptime` don't go further than second precision; that seems fine for the use case here, though, where you're not actually using the second-precision data)

Comment: (btw, bash and sh are definitely not the same thing; even if sh is a symlink to bash on your OS, it turns off some features when started under the `sh` name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq provides access to your local operating system's `strftime` and `strptime` functions. (Note that one needs to be careful about portability when using these: Some libc implementations provide more operators than POSIX guarantees).

```bash
jq '
  .[0].released_at |                # extract field
  split(".")[0] |                  # strip seconds (not portably parsable)
  strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") |  # parse with strptime
  strftime("%A, %B, %Y")           # format with strftime
' <<'EOF'
[
  {"released_at": "2023-09-27T17:36:07.182Z"}
]
EOF
```

...emits as output:

```json
"Wednesday, September, 2023"
```

Comment: This did the trick`jq '.[0].released_at | split(".")[0] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") | strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")')`, `jq '.[0].` instead of `jq '.[].`

Comment: Alternatively `jq -r '.[0].released_at | .[0:19]+"Z" | fromdateiso8601 | strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Linux based operating system, the [GNU `date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command can format times and understands timestamps given in ISO-8601 format:

```bash
$ date -d "$released_at" +"%A, %B %d, %Y"
Wednesday, September 27, 2023
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't call `date` from jq (which deliberately doesn't have any features allowing things so insecure as invoking arbitrary commands), so how does this answer the question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, but you can call it from a shell script, either with the variable OP shows setting in their question (Which is of course what I used), or directly with `date -d "$(... | jq -r '.[0].released_at')" ...`

Comment: Yup, but that's in the general case a lousy approach -- if you have a jq program that's iterating over thousands of records, you don't want to replace it with thousands of shell commands running thousands of copies of `/bin/date`. And jq _has_ built-in date-parsing and date-formatting functions; why not use them?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Where does iterating over thousands of records come from?

Comment: "in the general case" -- I'm making the point that this is an answer that only works in trivial cases. We know the input  structure is an array, or there wouldn't be a `.[0]`, so it certainly can have more than _one_ record.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If OP *isn't* doing something trivial, they should update their question to be closer to the actual use case.

Comment: I disagree. When the OP says "how do I do X with jq?", an answer should tell them how to do X _with jq_ in a way that's just as flexible and useful in as many and varied scenarios as jq itself is. Deciding that when they said "with jq" they didn't really mean it and a workaround that uses different tools (with wildly different performance characteristics) (and which, for that matter, _doesn't even talk about jq at all_) is a perfectly acceptable answer... I can't see it.

Comment: To put it a little differently: If the OP asked the question without anywhere mentioning jq, we would have had plenty of candidate duplicates to close the question with. Would you have thought it reasonable and appropriate if I had in fact closed the question with a question asking about GNU date as the linked duplicate, and where someone had given the same answer you do here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't have a problem with a duplicate like that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Providing solutions to the OP's specific problem is great. Providing more general solutions (with a whole different set of problems) is also great. *Neither* should be discouraged. (As for problems with your more general jq solution, jq before 1.7 had huge bugs in its date-time functions. And you're ignoring the TZ offset, assuming a constant `Z` while the format appears to be ISO8601 or RFC3339 which support `±hh:mm` in addition to `Z`. So is your solution really that much more general?)

Comment: @ikegami, I agree that there are problems, and that it's worth calling out the caveats. I don't agree that an answer _that doesn't use or even acknowledge the existence of jq at all_ belongs anywhere on a jq-specific question -- just as we don't allow Python answers to Java questions, C answers to SQL questions, etc. We _already have_ general-purpose "how does one do this in shell?" questions with answers attached; "how does one do this in jq?" _is a separate question_. If one could shell out from jq to `date` it'd be worth showing how to do that, but jq deliberately doesn't have that support.

Comment: @ikegami (...and the hypothetical "this is how you run `date` as a subprocess of jq" answer would be an answer _demonstrating jq syntax_, making it squarely on-topic).

Comment: @Charles Duffy It's called an [X-Y problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). The fact that they say they want to use X (`jq`) doesn't mean it's actually the best solution for them. Using Y (`date`) could be. Our answers handle X-Y problems day in and day out. Also, note the question was tagged [tag:sh]. Maybe `date` isn't a good solution for them (or another reader), but you're not in a position to decide that. Whether the solution gets used or not, everyone is richer by having this answer posted.